# TypeError: sequence item 0 expected str instance, bytes found

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am doing a Python challenge but when in mission 6 I met some problems:

```
comments = []
comments.append(file_zip.getinfo('%s.txt'%name).comment)
print(''.join(comments))
```

but this give me the error:

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found

I looked for the answer, and have a try like this:

```
print(b''.join(comments))
```

it works and prints:

```
b'***************************************************************\n****************************************************************\n**                                                    **\n**   OO    OO    XX    YYYY    GG    GG  EEEEEE NN      NN  **\n**    OO    OO  XXXXXX   YYYYYY   GG
    GG   EEEEEE  NN    NN   **\n**   OO    OO XXX  XXX YYY   YY  GG GG     EE       NN  NN    **\n**    OOOOOOOO XX    XX YY        GGG       EEEEE     NNNN     **\n**   OOOOOOOO XX    XX YY        GGG       EEEEE      NN      **\n**   OO    OO XXX  XXX YYY   YY  GG GG     EE         NN      **\n**
 OO    OO  XXXXXX   YYYYYY   GG   GG   EEEEEE     NN      **\n**   OO      OO         XX       YYYY    GG    GG  EEEEEE     NN
```

I think it regards `'/n'` as a char and print it, but, I don't want that. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue is that `file_zip.getinfo('%s.txt'%name).comment` apparently returns a `bytes` object(s). When you try and join on an `str`, namely `''.join(..)` you get the error:

```
''.join([b'hello', b'\n', b'world'])    
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found
```

Joining on `b''` is a viable alternative but, as you note, it doesn't escape special characters like `'\n'`; that's expected behavior for `bytes` instances.

You can either `decode` the string after it has been `join`ed on `b''`:

```
print(b''.join(comments).decode())
```

Or, `decode` every element of `comments` with `map` and `join` on an empty string `''` as you originally attempted:

```
print(''.join(map(bytes.decode, comments)))
```